# Can a client dictate whether or not HttpContext is created?

Tags: asp.net, http, webforms, httpwebrequest, httpcontext

We are getting a lot of hits from Googlebot and BingBot and it appears that none of these requests have an HttpContext.

I originally thought that every http request will get a context which obviously is not the case so I'm trying to understand how does an HttpContext gets constructed, is it part of the negotiation between client and server?

Comment: What method are these requests using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The client *doesn't* dictate this in any way, in what context are you checking for `HttpContext`?  Are you sure `HttpContext.Current` is null? (And you're not looking at `HttpContext.Current.Session`?)

There are some places in the lifecycle where it is unavailable, but this won't vary from client to client.

If you're curious as to more details, I recommend [A low-level Look at the ASP.NET Architecture](http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/howaspnetworks/howaspnetworks.asp) by Rick Strahl, he gives an overview of where things are created/destroyed in the request lifecycle...this hasn't changed a great deal since it was written.